# Requery from failed mongo replica instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replication, high-availability

I have a node app which runs in a cluster and a mongo replica set of 3 instances.
App uses native mongodb driver (https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb).
When mongo instance fails (crash or connection issue) with executing a query, client receives 500 error. It's possible to redirect failed query to another mongo instance?

Sorry for my English)

Comment: The best way is to sense the exception arisen by the failure and then act on that failure

Answer (score -1):

If the primary crashes, then by definition it won't be able to point you to another secondary. You'll have to deal with the secondary endpoints in your code. I don't use mongodb native, just mongoose, but the seudocode would be

```
var connection=new connection(primary server);
var query="{...}";

connection.runquery(query,function(err,response) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error, will retry with secondary');
        var connection2=new connection(secondary server);
        connection2.runquery(query,function(err2, response2) {
            if(err2) {
                console.log('Error, replica secondary is also down. OMG');
            } else {
                console.log(response2);
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank for reply.
I'm using 'secondaryPreferred' option in replSet.
Proposed method will work, but it's like new driver implementation plus its too expensive to rewrite and support all error handlers for requery feature.